# NgXs @selector doesn't support async functions

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

Inside my NGXS store I have the following async selector

```
@Selector()
static async mainState(store: IMyStore): Promise<IMyState> {
    return this.getActiveState(store);
}
```

If I now subscribe to this selector

```
@Select(MyStore.mainState) state$: Observable<IMyState>;
```

If I subscribe to this stream I receive promises not IMyState objects. So I have to do:

```
this.state$.subscribe(p => {
    p.then(state => { ... });
});
```

I can cast the promise into a rxjs stream but then I receive streams

```
this.state$.subscribe(s => {
    s.subscribe(state => { ... });
});
```

So my question is, is there a way to support async selectors in ngxs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [@Selector](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select) is used to "slice a specific portion of the state from the global state container" (not to call `async` function within it as I know).

You can achieve what you're trying to do, like the following:

- Create a new `@Action` to handle the `async` process.
- Add a new property to your state to hold the `mainState` value.
- After getting the result from `async` function, update the `mainState` with the proper value.
- Create a new `@Selector` function to return the `mainState`.
- Dispatch the created `action` within your component.
- Add `@Select` property within your component to get the `mainState` from your state.

Your code could look like the following:

**mystore.state.ts**

```js
@Selector()
static mainState(state: IMyStore): IMyState {
    return state.mainState;
}

@Action(LoadMainState)
async loadMainState(ctx: StateContext<IMyStore>) {
  const _activeState = await this.getActiveState(store);
  ctx.patchState({ mainState: _activeState });
}
```

**example.component.ts**

```js
@Select(MyStore.mainState) state$: Observable<IMyState>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(new LoadMainState());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you still don't want to create an awkward piece of store you can flatten with switchAll(). Doing so you avoid ugly subscribe inside subscribe.

```
@Select(MyStore.mainState) stateHigherOrder$: Observable<Observable<IMyState>>;
state$!:Observable<IMyState>;    

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.state$ = this.stateHigherOrder$.pipe(switchAll());
}
```

And now this.state$ is what you wanted